# Ant build trace call to class

Tags: java, ant, build-script

My build script is failing because it is building class A before the dependency is built.

Is there a way to trace when exactly class A is being loaded during compilation? I know the task which fails but the task is compiling other classes C,D,E and There is no direct relations between them. The compiled classes import a Class B which is extended by Class A.

Like

```
Import Class B

Class C
{
}

Class A extends Class B
{
}
```

I am using eclipse to debug this. Ant verbose mode did not help either.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Ant has two debug flags, -d (debug) and -v (verbose) - if you enable both of those I think you should get some useful info.

Comment: I ve used this. It does show me the last java file that compiled before trying to compile class A  but still not sure why its been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling all classes in the same `javac` task, then `javac` (the executable) will determine the correct dependency order.

However, if you are intending to compile class A sometime after class B has been compiled, then you need to ensure the class file for B is in the classpath of the `javac` target for compiling A.

For example:

```
<javac srcdir="b-project/src" destdir="classes"/>
```

... then sometime later, perhaps in another target (set the `depends` attribute) ...

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="classes"/><!-- contains compiled class B -->
</path>
<javac classpathref="compile.classpath" srcdir="a-project/src" destdir="classes"/>
```

If this doesn't help you then please post the relevant portions of your build file.